# Close each webdriver that open every 30 sec using python selenium

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Hy, I want to execute multiple browsers continuously, but when each browser open then each browser should be closed every 30 sec

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


with open('configure.txt','r') as f:
  config = f.readlines()
  l= config[0].strip('\n').split('|')[1].strip(' ')
  print(l)
  # 2nd line
  t = config[1].strip('\n').split('|')[1].strip(' ')
  print(t)
with open('proxies.txt','r') as f:
i=f.readline()
def web():
  print(i)
  option.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % i)
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=option)
  driver.execute_script(f'''window.open("{l}","_blank");''')
  time.sleep(2)
  driver.close()
  time.sleep(30)
  driver.quit()





 for i in range(0,5):
   web()
```

Answer (score 0):

You definitely *could* use multithreading for this but I'd advise you to at least look into [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently). Instead of spawning threads manually and `wait()`'ing for them to complete. You can just schedule events on an event loop. Below is a small code sample to illustrate your use case.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import asyncio
import random


async def open_and_close():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver.execute_script(f"""window.open("{"http://google.com"}","_blank");""")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    driver.close()
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0, 10))
    driver.quit()


async def main():
    # Schedule multiple browser actions *concurrently*:
    funcs = [open_and_close() for i in range(5)]

    L = await asyncio.gather(*funcs)


asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: thx for the code, but it works when the loop end, is there another solution when a browser open when it complete-time (10 sec), etc then close while running in the loop

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean but you can put this code block inside of a loop:

```python
while True:
    funcs = [open_and_close() for i in range(5)]
    await asyncio.gather(*funcs)
```

Comment: I mean u set loop run 5 times  inside this loop each browser open then each browser should be close after 30 sec  but browsers are close when looping ends

Comment: No each browser is closed after 30 seconds, they don't all close at the same time. It may feel like that because all the browsers are started at the exact same time.

If you want to test this, try sleeping for a random number of seconds instead using `random.randint(0, 30)`.

Comment: not close all the browsers close at the same time after 30, when a browser open and it time starts when it completes its time then it should be closed  that's the thing i asked you

Comment: Yes, that is actually what is happening in the above code. It only looks like its all closing after 30 seconds because they are all started at the same time. Take a look at my edited code to see an example that you can run and verify.

Comment: if u understand my question can u update this code that exactly i asked you and send me plz

Comment: yes this code is updated I want to close every 30